# How can add multiple collection in shopify liquid for loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, shopify, liquid

I want to show products from the collections selected from theme setting.
Here is my code:

```
{% assign col1 = collections[settings.collection1] %}
{% assign col2 = collections[settings.collection2] %}
{% assign col = [col1, col2] %}
   {% for product in col .products %}
     {{ product }}
   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this

```
   {% for i in (1..2) %}
   {% capture col %}collection{i}{% endcapture %}

   {% for product in collecitons.settings[col] %}
    {{product}}
   {% endfor %}

   {% endfor %}
```